# Looking up IPs and writing to file in Bash

Tags: scripting, ip-address

I'm trying to reverse lookup a list of hostnames to find their IPs and write to a file. I'm referring to [this](https://blog.zencoffee.org/2013/12/dynamic-dns-filtering-nginx/) tutorial and expand on it to work with a list of hostnames. I'm new to Bash scripting and here's what I came up with which does not print as desired,

```
for name in hostA.com hostB.com hostC.com;
do
    host $name | grep "has address" | sed 's/.*has address //' |
    awk '{print "allow\t\t" $1 ";" }' > ./allowedip.inc
done
```

Comment: The first thing I noted is that you'll want to use append (`>>`) instead of write (`>`) to redirect the output.  Otherwise, your file will only contain the last item from your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dig`:

```bsh
for host in hostA.com hostB.com hostC.com
do
    # get ips to host using dig
    ips=($(dig "$host" a +short | grep '^[.0-9]*$'))
    for ip in "${ips[@]}";
    do
        printf 'allow\t\t%s\n' "$ip"
    done
done > allowedip.inc
```

Output:

```bsh
$ cat allowedip.inc
allow       64.22.213.2
allow       67.225.218.50
allow       66.45.246.141
```

---

Loop through a file with one host per line:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r host;
do
    # get ips to host using dig
    ips=($(dig "$host" a +short | grep '^[.0-9]*$'))
    for ip in "${ips[@]}";
    do
        printf 'allow\t\t%s\n' "$ip"
    done
done < many_hosts_file > allowedip.inc
```

Comment: A given host can have more than one IP address. The `tail -n1` will not get all of them..

Comment: Am I sure that some hostnames have multiple A records? Yes, that is pretty standard, for load balancing reasons. Am I sure that `tail -n1` will remove all lines except one? Yes, that is pretty much the definition of the `tail` command. Not convinced? Compare `dig google.com +short | tail -n1` to `dig google.com +short`. Also please use RFC2606 names in your examples

Comment: @RoVo If I have a long list of hosts, how can I break each hostname in a newline? Or should I import the names from a separate file?

Comment: added way to do this from file.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, I fixed that, using `grep` instead of `tail` and loop through all ips that have been found.

Answer (score 0):

example of grep:

```
$ host google.com|grep -oP "has address \K.*"                                                  
216.58.214.238
```